# Finding the characteristic polynomial of a matrix modulus n

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, polynomials

Given a square matrix, is it possible to calculate its characteristic polynomial modulo `n`?
Unfortunately, this function [`CharacteristicPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) doesn't have the [`Modulus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Modulus.html?q=Modulus&lang=en) option that many other functions have.

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for the `Modulus`  option in `CharacteristicPolynomial`, since  [`PolynomialMod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialMod.html?q=PolynomialMod&lang=en) serves that purpose. Assume we have a matrix `m` e.g. :

```
m = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}]
m // MatrixForm
```

> ```
> {{10, 1, 4, 10, 9}, {1, 9, 6, 1, 5}, {9, 7, 9, 1, 0}, {1, 10, 8, 0, 4}, {4, 0, 4, 7, 10}}
> ```

[image]

then

```
CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x]
```

> ```
> 2310 - 4008 x + 1739 x^2 - 370 x^3 + 38 x^4 - x^5
> ```

while e.g. a characteristic polynomial modulo `5` is :

```
PolynomialMod[ CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x], 5]
```

> ```
> 2 x + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^5
> ```

**Edit**

If there are specific reasons for a characteristic polynomial different than knowing its `PolynomialMod`,  one can use directly `Modulus` in  functions like `Solve`, `Factor` or other with that option.

Let us factor `PolynomialMod[ CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x], 5]` as well as  `CharacteristicPolynomial[m, x]` over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ :

```
Factor[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x], Modulus -> 5]

Factor[ PolynomialMod[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x], 5], Modulus -> 5] ===
  Factor[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x], Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> 4 x (3 + x + 2 x^3 + x^4)
>
> True
> ```

analogically with `Solve`, e.g. :

```
Solve[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x] == 0, x, Modulus -> 5]

Solve[ PolynomialMod[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x], 5] == 0, x, Modulus -> 5] ==
  Solve[ CharacteristicPolynomial[ m, x] == 0, x, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0}}
> True
> ```

Therefore the option `Modulus -> n` in `CharacteristicPolynomial` would be superfluous.

Consider another simple polynomial :

```
p2 = PolynomialMod[ -1 + 4 x^2, 5]
p1 = Factor[        -1 + 4 x^2, Modulus -> 5]
```

> ```
> 4 + 4 x^2
> 4 (2 + x) (3 + x)
> ```

apparently they are different, however they are certainly the same modulo `5`, i.e. :

```
PolynomialMod[ p1 - p2, 5]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```