# How to compute the eigenvalue of a matrix over a finite field

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, finite-fields, eigenvalues

How to compute the eigenvalue of a matrix over a finite field?

I would like to compute the eigenvalues of the following matrix over $\mathbb F_5$.

```
Eigenvalues[{{2,-2,0,-1,-1},{2,2,-2,2,-2},{0,0,-1,1,0},{0,0,1,2,-2},{0,0,-2,2,2}}, Modulus->5]
```

But I get the error output:

> Eigenvalues
>   :UnknownoptionModulusinEigenvalues[{{2,-2,0,-1,-1},{2,2,-2,2,-2},{0,0,-1,1,0},{0,0,1,2,-2},{0,0,-2,2,2}},Modulus5].

**Question**: Is calculating the eigenvalue over a finite field possible in mathematica?

Comment: Take a look at a closely related issue [Finding the characteristic polynomial of a matrix modulus n](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/finding-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix-modulus-n/8078#8078)

Comment: In addition to the remark by @Artes, also note the roots of the char poly do not all lie in the base field: `In[179]:= Factor[
 CharacteristicPolynomial[{{2, -2, 0, -1, -1}, {2, 2, -2, 2, -2}, {0, 
    0, -1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 2, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 2, 2}}, x], 
 Modulus -> 5]

Out[179]= 4 (2 + x)^2 (4 + x) (3 + x^2)`